# Specify a valid entry to edit - Safecracker Error

Tags: safecracker, error

I've run into this before, however, for whatever reason I can't seem to resolve it this time. Whenever I submit my safecracker form below, I receive the following error:

*The form you submitted contained the following errors
You must specify a valid entry to edit.*

My hidden fields show the correct entry_id, etc. What am I doing wrong?

```
{if segment_4=="issue"}

{if segment_6 == "success"}
    <div class="alert fade in">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
        <strong>Success</strong> Issue has been updated.
    </div>     
{/if}


{exp:safecracker
limit="1"
channel="issue"
return="/myfig/{segment_2}/edit/issue/ENTRY_ID/success" 
datepicker="yes"
include_jquery="no"
entry_id="{segment_5}"
safecracker_head="no"
error_handling="inline"
use_live_url="no"
author_only="no"
}

    <label>Title</label>
    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="{title}" /><br />

    <label>Rate</label>

    <div class="input-prepend">
        <span class="add-on">$</span>
        <input type="text" name="rate" id="rate" value="{rate}" />
    </div>
    <label>Publish Date</label>
    <input type="text" name="publish_date" id="publish_date" value="{exp:low_nice_date date='{publish_date}' format='%m/%d/%Y'}" /><br />
    <label>Date Signed</label>
    <input type="text" name="date_signed" id="date_signed" value="{exp:low_nice_date date='{date_signed}' format='%m/%d/%Y'}"><br />

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Update" />


{/exp:safecracker}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could the `lmit="1"` parameter be causing problems?